# plot log likelihood function evolution in mcmc simulations

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood, gibbs

Is it possible to plot log likelihood function evolution in mcmc simulations?
I have a mixture model and its parameters are estimated using the gibbs sampling method in r environment and using the r2jags package.
I want to trace the log likelihood function evolutions in iterations to present the model convergence.
Is it possible?
How can I best present the convergence of the model?

Comment: Yes, you can follow the value of the likelihood function across MCMC iterations to check you have reached a stable regime of your Markov chain. This is for instance advised as a simple convergence diagnosis in our [book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441915753?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441915753)...

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve this with r2jags?  If yes, perhaps helpful to add tag R.

Comment: Dear Xi'an, thanks for your response, is it possible to introduce the exact section of the book that is related to this computation?? i am not so familiar with this issue and i can not find the required information from your book. thanks. regards.

Comment: Actually, it is in both [Bayesian Core [p.197.202. 214)](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441922865/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441922865) and in [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods (2004, p.428, Fig. 12.6)](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441919392?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441919392)...